# Wordpress same postnames adds -2 using different categorienames

Tags: wordpress

hopefully someone can help .. i am using the following permalink structure /%category%/%postname%/

what happens is using the same postname in a different category results in:

mysite.com/first-category/post-name
mysite.com/second-category/post-name-2

URLS are not identical due to different cat names, but still URLs result in an additional -2 as the postnames are identical

Is there a way to get rid of these -2 additions?

My .htaccess is standard WP;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are you only trying to use the same post name or is it a duplicate post in 2 different categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wp_posts table, post name is a primary key and also it is defined as unique
[image]

So, you can't have same post name even those are in two different categories

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Ajith, can you suggest a workaround, would custom post types help in this situation? so the url will be mysite.com/cpt1/post-name mysite.com/second-category/post-name and mysite.com/cpt2/post-name mysite.com/second-category/post-name

Comment: No, as the database column is a primary key, it SHOULD be definitely identical. You never can have similar post names. You will have to think of a way to have different post names by appending prefix or something similar. Please mark my answer so that others can see that you got the right answer.

Comment: Its pleasure as you got the answer. But sad that unable to help you to find alternative solution.